# Is there an actual HTTP client library available for Android?

Tags: java, android, http

I've been working with Android development a little bit lately, and I've come to the conclusion that the people who designed the so-called AndroidHttpClient and related code had to have been from the Chrome team at Google, because these libraries are clearly intended for someone who wants to build a browser, not someone who wants to *use an HTTP client as part of their software*.

In coding I've done in the past, an HTTP client library is essentially a web browser minus the renderer.  You specify a request, and it returns exactly what the user would have received had they submitted the same request in a web browser.  But AndroidHttpClient does not do this.  Specifically, it does not follow redirects, nor does it handle cookies, without a lot of careful intervention by the developer.  (Trying to mix the two, by POSTing a login to a server that returns a session cookie and a 302 redirect and then attempting to retrieve the same HTML that the hypothetical user in a web browser would end up seeing rendered, is a surprisingly difficult task.)

Someone I discussed this with recommended [Android Async-HTTP](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/), which I took a look at.  It makes setting up the POST request and dealing with the reply much simpler, but still does not handle redirects (and makes redirect handling even harder, in fact) and still places the burden of handling cookies on the developer instead of the library.

So I'm asking here.  Are there any libraries for Android that act as an *actual HTTP client*, as in "functions like a browser minus the renderer"?  I'm looking for a library that allows me to define a GET or POST request, call a method, give me back a `String` containing the same HTML that a web browser would end up rendering, and keep the implementation details out of my hair.

Does anything like that exist for Android?

Comment: An http client sends http request and receives http responses. Following 302s and saving cookies and session ids is up to the client (not the http client) code. Consider Apache's HttpClient stack.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: Performing extremely common tasks and getting them right so that wheels don't need to be reinvented is the responsibility of the library, not of the developer.  Most of the horribly deficient built-in code I'm grumbling about *is* Apache's HttpClient stack.  I'm wondering if there are any libraries that get it right.

Comment: IMO That's what configuration is about. For example, with Apache you can configure request factory to follow 302 responses, but how can the request factory know that 2 separate requests should use the same cookie unless you tell it.

Comment: For somebody with as much rep as you have, you should know better than to post rants. Beyond that, when you used a search engine to search for `android http client library` and `java http client library`, what did you learn?

Comment: If the AndroidHttpClient doesn't suit your needs, I would urge you to consider just using the [Apache HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/).  As @SotiriosDelimanolis said, everything that you've requested can most likely be setup in configuration.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Most people with as much rep as I have date back to the early days of SO. ;)  And when Googling for `android http client library`, the top result is for Android Async-HTTP, which I discussed in my post, and most of the ones underneath it are links to SO or other forum/discussion sites, documentation, or what appear to be obsolete libraries designed to fix bugs in much earlier Android versions.  So I'm asking actual people with actual experience, instead of turning to a search engine.

Comment: In ~90 seconds, I find http://java.dzone.com/articles/android-%E2%80%93-volley-library and http://square.github.io/okhttp/ and http://www.recursiverobot.com/post/49046560736/a-much-simpler-http-lib-for-android for the `android` search. OkHttp will not help you much, but Volley and the HttpRequest library pointed to by the third link (http://kevinsawicki.github.io/http-request/) may be more up your alley. Beyond that, "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."